# Python error TypeError: must be string or buffer, not instance

Tags: python, typeerror, urllib

i am trying to download some images which are listed in QListWidget i am passing the links to the urllib but its giving me ***TypeError: must be string or buffer, not instance*** this error. I tried looking up here but couldn't find any solution here is my code. Thanks

```
    def downloadStuff(self):
    files = self.listWidget.selectedItems()
    for filename in files:
        filename = filename.text()
        filename = str(filename)
        print filename
        xfilename = filename.split('/')[-1]
        with open('D:/'+xfilename,'wb') as imageFile:
            print filename
            imageFile.write(urllib.urlopen(filename)).read()
        imageFile.close()
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting. Your indentation is off, so this code wouldn't actually run. `imageFile` doesn't need to be closed. The whole point of using `with` is so you don't have to manage those kinds of resources. And include the whole stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say for sure without seeing the stack trace, but I suspect this line:

```
imageFile.write(urllib.urlopen(filename)).read()
```

Should instead be:

```
imageFile.write(urllib.urlopen(filename).read())
```

Incidentally, you don't need the `imageFile.close()` line, because the `with` statement closes the file for you automatically.

Comment: Yes bro you are right. Thanks a lot  it working now :)

Comment: oh okay.. i'll remove it :)

Comment: And hey bro can you tell me is there any way to know the file size before downloading ?

Comment: It's possible in principle since that data should be in the file header, but sorry, I don't know how exactly to get it. Perhaps you could ask that as a separate question.

Comment: Cool.. Anyways thanks again bro .