# TypeError: argument 1 must be string or buffer, not instance

Tags: python, urllib2

I'm having problem with my app in python my app is for downloading videos from the web at a specified time. my program name is tidopy.py
but I get this Error:

**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tidopy.py", line 29, in 
    file.write(data)
TypeError: argument 1 must be string or buffer, not instance**

I have problem with this part:

```
while (coun > x):
    file = open(namelist[x], 'wb')
    file.write(urllib2.urlopen(addresslist[x])).read()
    file.close()
    x = x + 1
```

**x** is a variable for the number of videos.

**namelist** is a list for the name of videos.

**addresslist** is a list for the address of web videos

How can I fix it?
please help.

Comment: I think you just need to fix this: `file.write(urllib2.urlopen(addresslist[x]).read())` . the read is activated on the urlopen instead of the write.

Comment: Do you understand what this line is doing: `file.write(urllib2.urlopen(addresslist[x])).read()`?

Comment: And that's why you shouldn't do four different things in a single line.

Comment: Answer to a remarkably similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40894945/95852

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code to perform a download from a list.

```
import requests
import shutil

namelist = [...]
addresslist = [...]

for k, x in enumerate(namelist):
    r = requests.get(x, stream=True)
    if r.ok:
        with open(addresslist[k], 'wb') as f:
            r.raw.decode_content = True
            shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
```

Comment: This does not attempt to address the problem, and goes in a completely different direction from OP's code.